# HITTING SET Problem

Tags: algorithms

HITTING SET 
INSTANCE: collection C of subsets of a set S, positive integer K. 
QUESTION: Does C contain a hitting set for C of size K or less, that is, a subset S' of S with |S'| <= K and such that S' contains at least one element from each subset in C

Prove that HITTING SET  is NP-Complete problem?

Comment: What is your question? It looks like a homework given to you, but we are not homework cheating service, so what is your question to us?

Comment: Prove that Hitting Set problem is in NP-Complete . That is the question ?

Comment: No, that is a statement or literally request. It ends with “?”, but still looks like a statement. How does a question look? First you start what you did try, where found obstacles and then ask how to overcome these obstacles. “How can I do ... in this step after I did ...?”